# Check if string equals quotation marks

Tags: java

I am trying to check if a string equals quotation marks (`"`). However, `string.equals(""")` does not work since it thinks I have an extra quotation mark. How can I check if the string equals quotation marks?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
str.equals("\"");
```

`\` is used as an escape character to tell the compiler that the next character is to be interpreted literally. In this case, it causes the `"` to be interpreted as a character in the string instead of as a ending quotation mark. `\"` is used to represent `"`.

To be safer with null strings, you can also do:

```
"\"".equals(str);
```

This will return false if `str` is null instead of throwing a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the escape character `\`. This lets it know the next character should be read as text and not interpreted by the compiler. `string.equals("\"")` will work.

Answer (score 1):

`string.equals("\"")` will work. This "\" functions as escape character.

Answer (score -1):

Please read the following article on "Escape Sequences".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Here is a small method in Java:

```
private boolean equalsDoubleQuote(String string)    
{
    /*
     *  The compiler will not be able to read three double-quote characters in 
     *    align.
     *  In this case, you use a the back-slash character.
     *  It will 'escape' the character after it, allowing the compiler to
     *    read it properly
     */
    return string.equals("\"");
}
```

The following encapsulation will not work because the compiler will find the first `*/` and stop the block comment there, expecting the following the text to be code.

This is obviously not the best comparison (because you cannot escape a string, `*/`).  The concept should be clear though.

```
void example()
{
    /*
     * 
     * What does the compiler do when I place
     * 
     *         a */ right here 
     *   
     */
}
```